# VB.net prevent a tooltip from showing

Tags: vb.net, tooltip

In my program i use tooltips to help new users have some idea of what the icon buttons do. I also have an option to turn tooltips off.

There appears to be a `tooltip.hide` method, but i don't quite understand how to use it.

So how do i get a tooltip to not display if a boolean value is set to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Active](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.active.aspx) property should meet your needs, it's more simple than using the [Hide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.hide.aspx) and [Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.show.aspx) methods.

```
'Hide ToolTip
ToolTip.Active = False

'Show ToolTip
ToolTip.Active = True
```

Comment: Hmm seems quite obvious. It works, though you can't use the popup showing event to reverse it... Which doesn't matter because i can reverse it when i change the checked value of my option.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`tooltip.Hide()` is used to hide the `ToolTip` while is being shown.

If you want the tooltips now showing you can put a condition when calling to the point that shows them:

```
If Not chkBoxNoToolTips.Checked Then
    tooltip1.Show()
End If
```

Or you can remove the tooltips from its controls if they are automatically set:

```
tooltip1.SetToolTip(label1, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Call SetToolTip and pass through your control and an empty string, you could probably pass through a null reference also but I haven't tried it myself.

This should remove the tooltip for you

```
ToolTip1.SetToolTip(txtBox1, "")
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This is good, but is there a way to figure out what object the tooltip is appearing for? need a more global method.